# calling a presenter from another file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a couple of presenters and put them in a folder called presenters in the app folder e.g app/presenters/....rb files

I call him in the controller using the following command

```
 @presenter = AgreementsPresenter.new(agreements)
```

I would now like to version them and put them in a folder called v1 under the presenters folder

What changes do I need to make to do this?

I think I will have to change the code to

@presenter = V1::AgreementsPresenter.new(agreements)

but unsure what other changes i need to make.

Regards

Gurdipe

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `V1` is the namespace so you will need to add the `AgreementsPresenter` to a module/class of that name. Some thing like this:

```
module V1
  class AgreementsPresenter
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `agreements_presenter.rb` file you moved to `app/presenters/v1/`

Comment: thanks tom, its still not working for me , im probably doing something silly

Comment: hi tom i had to add change the line of code to @presenter = ::V1::AgreementsPresenter.new(agreements) then it worked